# How to install Laravel in only the shared host's public folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I'm learning Laravel. I have been told that it for security reason shouldn't be installed on a shared host. But I wanna do that anyway since that the only option I have right now.

So, I have Googled to find out how to "install Laravel on shared host". But all instructions are based on that you place the project outside the host's public/web folder and then copying the Laravel public to the host's public and change the paths in index file.

But I can't do that since I don't have permission to add or change anything in the parent folder of the public folder on my host. So I need a solution where Laravel is installed in the public folder.

I know, that's absolutely not a recommended solution. But I wanna do this anyway in this learning stage.

How do I setup the whole Laravel package in the host's public folder?

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: Create a Linux Virtual Machine...choose any distro...and works there :)

Comment: And it might depend on your web hosting provider, a lot of providers can give you a `jailed shh` (if you ask for) for account so you can have access to parent folder and you can also run composer

Comment: Buglinjo, I think it's 5.1. Hackerman and Vitalii Strimbanu, I would most like to know if it's possible to do it the way I asked for, and how.

Comment: The answer to your question is really, truly, "get a better host".

Answer (score 0):

As a side note; this is a bad idea. All of your code may be available for public view.

The easiest way to do this is just to copy Laravel into the /public folder.

Then, if you're using something like cPanel you can just change the root directory of your domain from `/` to `/public`

Comment: "All of your code will be available for public view." This is **not** true. It is a risk that a server misconfiguration might turn off PHP and expose the source, but it is not automatic nor particularly common.

Comment: As I said, I know the risks but want to do it anyway in this case. Can I change the domain root from ispconfig's DNS manager? What record?

Comment: @PeterWesterlund DNS doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Okay then I can't change the domain's root.

Comment: @Ceejayoz There are thousands of shared hosting providers. Many of which I have experience with. I'm sure I could identify several immediately that would expose this, so I suppose that depends on which. Either way, it's still a risk.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, it's a risk that your host will break PHP and expose the source. Laravel's keeping code out of the public folder is a very good security feature and a best practice for this reason. I'm merely saying that your assertion that it **will** expose the source is false.

Comment: @ceejayoz **will** to **may**.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not important, it would be much better security wise to place disallow from all htaccess files in the root directory.  Then, update the file in public to allow from all.  Then access your website using, http://example.com/public/ (you'll get 403 denied at http://example.com).

If you absolutely can't do that.

1. You would want to place an htaccess file (or equivalent if you are running nginx) that has disallow from all in the other laravel directories (ie vendor, app, storage, etc).  (I cannot provide this as it is different for Apache 2.2 vs Apache 2.4 vs Nginx, but you can google for the file contents.)
2. Then, move the contents of public to the domain root (ie up one level).
3. Then, edit the htaccess file for public to disallow access to all hidden files, artisan, composer.json, composer.lock, and any other files that laravel has in the root folder.
4. Then, in `index.php` modify the two require statements and remove the `../` before `bootstrap`.

I think this will work, but I haven't tried it so let me know if you get errors.

In any case, be absolutely certain that it is impossible to download the `.env` file as that is where all your passwords will be.  http://example.com/.env should give you 403 denied.  If that downloads, you are in trouble.